# git hook execution order

Tags: git, githooks

I see GIT provides a pre-commit and a commit-message hook...which is great...but I find it annoying that when I do a commit I have to wait for **all** my files to get linted and **all** my tests to run ***BEFORE*** I get told "sorry, you don't have JIRA-XXX in our commit message".

From what I read on the docs you can't change this order and the pre-commit hook doesn't have access to the commit message which hasn't been created yet.

is anybody else annoyed by this?  If so, what are others doing?

Answer (score 5):

You are totally right when you say the order cannot be changed. And hopefully IMO, otherwise it would be a total mess.

Concerning your issue, even if this is not *semantically* appropriate, I think the best solution would be to rely on the **commit-msg** hook to perform all the checks (the commit message syntax and your linting, in this order).

Also, since [version 1.8.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt), git enables to add a **pre-push** hook. Which you might also consider in your workflow.